# Meta tag invalid property attribute

Tags: html, meta-tags

I'm trying to change the default thumbnail pic facebook uses when I post my website url on fb. Now I've been on a couple of websites/forums and there is a lot of confusion/differences about it.
Most people say that you should include the following line in the `<head></head>` tag of your homepage:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="url to your desired thumbnail image.jpg" />
```

Now I did that (and so did many other people) and it doesn't work(for others as well). Some other folks on different websites suggested including the following:

```
<meta name="fb" content="url to your desired thumbnail image.jpg" property="og:image"/>
```

**In ASP.NET (visual studio '10) it says that `'property'` is not a valid attribute of 'meta'**.

Now what schemas should I declare in my html tags for property to be a 'valid' attribute. I went on some big websites to see their coding, and found the following meta tags declared in the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta content="IE=100" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

I tried that as well but fb still doesn't use the pic I specified to be used as the thumbnail. My coding and url's are not broken or anything, visual studio debugs it without problems.

Please help...

Thank You

Comment: property is not an attribute from the html standard, is an invent from the people of open graph protocol. because name is not enough for them

Comment: @Einacio: `property` is an attribute defined by RDFa, which can be used in HTML(5) documents. → http://www.w3.org/TR/html-rdfa/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following `<meta>` tag into your `<head>` section:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="URL_to_your_desired_thumbnail_image.jpg" />
```

Then, enter the URL of your page into the [Facebook URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint)

For 'property' to be a valid attribute of the `<meta>` tag, you might have to change your `<!DOCTYPE ...>`.